# Angular 9 ngbPopover not working on first load but works fine only when page is refreshed for dynamic content inside popover

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I am displaying popover like this which works completely fine only on refreshing the page. It's not showing the first time page is loaded.

```
<p ngbPopover triggers="hover" [popoverTitle]="order.name" container='body'>{{order.name}} </p>
```

Comment: Not sure if "hover" is an event in Angular. Maybe try triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave". See the example here: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpopover-triggers.html

Comment: @user2846469 I tried triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" this time it works fine the first time but not the second time onwards in mobile responsive view

Comment: Do you need the container='body'? I would only add that if you have a specific reason. Otherwise, try leaving it out and see if it helps.